# How to close previous running instance of process/application in python?

Tags: python

I'm newbie in python. I just want to close the previous running instance of a process or application.

My code below will only close the currently open process.

```
import os
import psutil

applicaton = "program.exe"

for p in psutil.process_iter():
    if p.name() == applicaton:
        process_id = p.pid
        if not p.pid == process_id:
            p.terminate()
```

Comment: do you want to close all the previously running process or a specific process?

Comment: I want to close all previously running process of the same application name.

Comment: I created a code to close all the process running in this particular name..

Comment: You care basically doing: `a=1; if a != 1 then ...` which can't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my latest code with the question above.

```
def close_app(app_name):
    prdt_lst = []
    pid_lst = []
    for proc in psutil.process_iter():
        if proc.name() == app_name:
            prdt = proc.create_time()
            prdt_lst.append(prdt)
            pid_lst.append(proc.pid)

    # print(prdt_lst)
    # print(pid_lst)

    if prdt_lst > [0]:
        (m, i) = max((v, i) for i, v in enumerate(prdt_lst))
        # print(m, i)

        for indx, value in enumerate(prdt_lst):
            if indx == i:
                continue

            # print(pid_lst[indx])
            psutil.Process(pid_lst[indx]).terminate()
```